# cannot get onvif GetStreamUri from media2

Tags: linux, ip-camera, onvif, python-onvif

I want to get the media stream url from onvif,but it shows that "Method 'GetStreamUri' not implemented: method name or namespace not recognized"Detail: [no detail] .
I don't know the reason why the method GetStreamUri not implemented?

I download wsdl "http://www.onvif.org/ver20/media/wsdl" and generate the code by using the gsoap.

[console ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C16YP.png)

I find the TEST.log.It shows that it cannot find ns3:GetStreamUri and ns1:GetStreamUri

[debug information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7BJB.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I add the debug information ,please help me to check what is wrong? @Bot

Answer (score 0):

Is your camera Profile T compliant or does it at least implement Media Service 2?

In not, then you should use Media Service 1.